# как установить свою иконку в Yii2

Tags: yii2

хотел бы изменить иконку сайта на свою в базовом шаблоне, но интернете нашел только

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>
/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

вот мне не понятно куда этот код вставить и как назвать, куда кинуть мою иконку, какие должны быть размеры

Answer (score 1):

Для yii2 я делал так.

Загрузил новую картинку web/images/favicon.ico

В файле шаблона views/layouts/main.php добавил пространство имён

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
```

и между тегами `<head></head>`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= Url::base() ?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя есть файл views/layouts/main.php , зайди туда и перед строкой <\head>" вставь  тэг, приведенный выше.
Потом перейди в папку web/images и закинь свою иконку(желательно одинаковой высоты и ширины)